"to stress out for something"
Is it ok to use the preposition "for or because of" with "stress out" as in:

Don´t stress out for / becuase of the interview.

I know the the most common prepositions are over and about but I´ve found constructions like:

Don´t stress out for no reason.
Don´t stress out for not having the confidence.

Therefore, I wonder if "for and because of" can be used with any other nouns or noun phrases.

"Don't stress out" can be followed by many different types of prepositional phrase. You can give a specific cause of stress ("over the exam", "on account of the interview"), but you can also refer more generally to a stressful situation ("in college"), give background causes of the stress ("from lack of sleep"), provide another characterisation ("without a good reason"), or give a duration, time phrase, etc ("for long", "when you're young"). The preposition will depend on the meaning, and this question is too vague to give a proper answer with every possible preposition.

@StuartF I see what you mean with prepositional phrases. To be more precise. Does "Don´t stress out for the interview" sound idiomatic to you? when indicating the cause of the stress.

"Don't stress out" can be followed by many different types of prepositional phrase. You can give a specific cause of stress ("over the exam", "on account of the interview"), but you can also refer more generally to a stressful situation ("in college"), give background causes of the stress ("from lack of sleep"), provide another characterisation ("without a good reason"), or give a duration, time phrase, etc ("for long", "when you're young"). The preposition will depend on the meaning, and this question is too vague to give a proper answer with every possible preposition. --Stuart F.
I think it's a shame when a question remains unanswered for more than a week because someone answered it with a comment rather than an answer. So I cut and pasted Stuart F.'s comment here as what seems to me to be a great answer. I take no credit for the answer itself.

Good idea to ensure useful material is retained. +1
